# salvar IMG de site externo

Tags: php, javascript, img

Será que existe a possibilidade de salvar uma imagem em uma pasta `/imagens` de um site externo?

Eu consigo salvar normal a imagem se eu clicar com o botão direito e colocar em *"Salvar imagem como"*, porém gostaria de saber como fazer isso em *JavaScript* ou *PHP*, eu inspecionei e o elemento é esse:

```
<img id="imagem" alt="Painel" src="http://appsite/caminho/caminho2/Content/caminho3/Painelimg/2018_03_02/08_03_28.PNG" style="width: 2790.72px; height: 391.68px;">
```

OBS: Essa imagem é gerada a cada 10 segundos, então por isso preciso salva-la automaticamente só que o nome da imagem é a hora atual, por exemplo, essa hora que inspecionei o nome da imagem é *08_03_28.png* ou seja era *08h:03m:28s* não preciso salvar todas posso sobrepô-las também, só preciso da imagem naquele momento pois farei outra função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há duas formas de fazer isso com *PHP*.

- Utilizando [file_get_contents](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php-)
- Utilizando [cURL](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)

**Exemplo com `file_get_contents`:**

Essa função irá acessar a página e baixar todo o seu conteúdo, para salvar, poderemos utilizar `fopen` ou `file_put_contents`.

```
<?php

while (true) {

    /* Captura a data atual */
    $date = date('Y_m_d');

    /* Captura o tempo patual */
    $time = date('H_i_s');

    /* Monta a URL com a data e o tempo */
    $url = "http://appsite/caminho/caminho2/Content/caminho3/Painelimg/{$date}/{$time}.PNG";

    /* Faz uma requisição para a URL e salva o conteúdo em binário na variável */
    $content = file_get_contents($url, FILE_BINARY);

    /* Cria o arquivo no servidor com o conteúdo baixado */
    file_put_contents( "{$time}.png", $content, FILE_BINARY );

    /* Aguarda 10 segundos */
    sleep(10);
}
```

Pronto! Está funcionando. O problema é que `while(true)` será infinito e portanto, você poderá ter um problema com os recursos do servidor.

Caso seja algo esporádico, não há problemas.

---

**Exemplo com `curl`:**

Essa função também irá fazer uma solicitação e retornar os dados, porém terá algumas linhas a mais. A vantagem é que ela é mais robusta que a função anterior.

Para salvar, poderemos utilizar `fopen` ou `file_put_contents`.

```
<?php

while (true) {

    /* Captura a data atual */
    $date = date('Y_m_d');

    /* Captura o tempo patual */
    $time = date('H_i_s');

    /* Monta a URL com a data e o tempo */
    $url = "http://appsite/caminho/caminho2/Content/caminho3/Painelimg/{$date}/{$time}.PNG";

    /* Cria o arquivo. Caso ele já exista, sobrepõe */
    $file = fopen("{$time}.png", "w+");

    /* Instancia o objeto */
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    /* Define as configurações */
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [

        /* Informa que deseja capturar o valor retornado */
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

        /* Indica o "Resource" do arquivo onde será salvado */
        CURLOPT_FILE           => $file
    ]);

    /* Fecha a conexão da requisição e do arquivo */
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($file);

    /* Aguarda 10 segundos */
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Percebi que a imagem pelo caminho que indiquei ela é toda preta porem no site ela é preta mas com algumas letras, acho que é feita em canvas, quando eu a salvo pelo mouse vem tudo certinho porém pelo código ou pelo link que eu postei direto da imagem vem toda preta, será q existe outra forma?

Comment: @Ixxtomxxl se possível posta o link da imagem, fica mais fácil de testar. É necessário verificar a extensão também. Você testou com as duas formas ou apenas uma delas?

Comment: então é q o link só funciona dentro da empresa, eu tentei pegar apenas a div que contem a imagem com file_gets_contents funcionou em outros sites, porem nesse não. Se tiver outra forma agradeço queria até te presentear com algo, se isso for possivel dentro das normas do site.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode fazer com o `NodeJs`.

Você pode utilizar o `http` para baixar a imagem e o `pipe` para escrever a imagem em seu sistema.

```
let output = fs.createWriteStream(file);

http.get(URL, response => {
    response.pipe(output);
});
```

**Código:**

```
const URL = "http://appsite/caminho/caminho2/Content/caminho3/Painelimg";
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

async function startDownload() {

    const date = new Date();

    /* Captura a data */
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
    let day = date.getDay().toString().padStart(2, "0");

    /* Captura o tempo */
    let hour = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
    let min = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
    let seconds = date.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");

    let datePath = `${year}_${month}_${day}`
    let file = `${hour}_${min}_${seconds}.PNG`

    /* Baixa a imagem */
    http.get(`${URL}/${datePath}/${file}`, async (response) => {
        await wait(10000);
        startDownload();
    });

};

function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) )
}

startDownload();
```

Answer (score 0):

você também pode utilizar a função `copy()` do php

```
bool copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] )
```

basicamente vai usar os 2 primeiros parametros

> source:  Caminho para o arquivo de origem.
>
> dest: O caminho de destino. Se o dest for uma URL, a cópia pode falhar
>   se o wrapper não suportar a sobrescrita de arquivos existentes.